# Tracking sales back to google adwords campaign

Tags: google-ads-api

hopefully this is not a little vague,
Wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction, I want to essentially be able to track new sales back to what ad words campaign they came from or potentially where did the click that led them to our page.

I have been exploring google analytics and can see clicks conversions etc on that but how would I even start wanting to tag sales in real time with what I need to map them back to GA data, is it the Google cookie id?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With google analytics, sessions will already be tagged properly with a source/medium of `google/cpc` and include the campaign URNs. The key to correlating those sessions to sales is to ensure your site is sending enhanced e-commerce events:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce

It's really not much different than sending a normal pageview event with Google Analytics. You just send a different event with the data structure that GA is expecting anytime a part of your funnel is viewed in a browser (product view, add to cart, checkout, etc).

Many e-commerce platforms like Shopify, WooCommerce, Magento, etc. have pre-built solutions for doing this. You should only need to build a custom solution if your site itself is custom built.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-e-commerce-for-woocommerce-store/
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/reports-and-analytics/google-analytics/google-analytics-setup
https://marketplace.magento.com/tatvic-tatvic-google-analytics-enhanced-ecommerce.html

*Full disclosure: I am not affiliated with any of these plugins or platforms, just providing links to the most popular enhanced e-commerce solutions for each one.*

Once your site site is properly configured to send the e-commerce events there are multiple ways to see which ads have resulted in sales. The easiest is under `Acquisition` > `Google Ads` > `Campaigns`. It will show you a breakdown of visitors and conversions by add URN:

[image]

You can also see a breakdown under `Acquisition` > `All Traffic` > `Source Medium`, though you'll have to add a secondary dimension to see the campaign URNs:

[image]

This latter one is a great view for correlating sales from other sources as well, such as organic, referral, etc.